# What is the new word for North Africans born in Spain?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I listened to the podcast Hoy Hablamos. The episode was called "Los chonis y las Chanis". They used a word for North African descendants living or born in Spain.

I think it comes from French but I couldn't get the French version of the word either. It seems to be an acronym, initials that can be pronounced as a word.

I couldn't find anything in any dictionary only Magrebi and Beurs. The latter seems to be pejorative.

I know "moros" is an old word also but that is not it either. I can't find the word as I don't know what it is to begin with. I I believe it is new. "Niños de la calle" was also mentioned in the podcast but I'm not sure that was related to North African descent or to the wider subject matter